# GitKraken crash on Fedora - "GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye."

Tags: crash, fedora, gitkraken

I'm running GitKraken 8.2.1 on Fedora and after upgrading from Fedora 34 to 35 GitKraken wouldn't start anymore, showing when started on command line following error:

```
$ /usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken

(node:71300) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:71300) [DEP0106] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createDecipher is deprecated.
(electron) 'allowRendererProcessReuse' is deprecated and will be removed.
state:  unavailable
[71300:0128/121858.313660:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(442)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
Failed to generate minidump.[1]    71300 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  /usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken
```

I tried purging and reinstalling GitKraken, removing the complete local config `~/.gitkraken`, turned on logging to `SILLY` but didn't get any further hints what's going on.

Interestingly I ran the same setup (Fedora 35 & GitKraken 8.2.1) on another machine which just works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I solved that issue. I found that GitKraken is based on EletronJS which has some [auxAttributes for GPU](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetgpuinfoinfotype).
These attributes can be altered via command line given that they are enabled via `app.commandLine.appendSwitch` command in the gitkraken EletronJS application. All these additional EletronJS related parameters are hidden from the command line parameters documented via `/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken -h`.

So the solution was for me to start GitKraken from command line using the ElectronJS attribute "InProcessGpu", which basically run the GPU process as a thread. To enable that feature simple start gitkraken wiht the attribute `--in-process-gpu`, e.g.

```
/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken --in-process-gpu &
```

Btw. I also found [another solution in the gitkraken forum](https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/201210/menu-setting-to-disable-gpu-usage-disablegpu) that completely disables GPU usage by calling `gitkraken --in-process-gpu`. This approach didn't work out for me though.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. I run into this today, after upgrading Manjaro